# addsubivew reloads tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, addsubview

I have a `view` which includes a `tableview`. I try to add another view as subview of this view as below:

```
[mainviewcontroller addChildViewController:subViewcontroller];
[mainviewcontroller.view addSubview:subViewcontroller.view];
```

When I do this the tableview is reloaded and go back to it's original position. What should I do to prevent this reloading?

I found the problem!
 as I'm using auto layout adding subview causes page refresh after adding subview. Is there any way to prevent this?!

Comment: don't really see a table reloading just because it is added to a view -- do YOU reload it somewhere?

Comment: @niloufar your question is not clear enough, can you please add some more details or code what you are trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The point is the both memory of the table view just have difference, and the both table view is not same “UITableView”, actually.

So the problem is not "reloadData", the problem is you have two table view or you create it and then create the another new one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I only have one table view which I add to my mainViewController in story board and then I'm trying to add another view as subview then it refresh tableview...

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the index of the selected cell and call it after.
Something like:

```
NSIndexPath* index = [yourTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
[mainviewcontroller addChildViewController:subViewcontroller];
[mainviewcontroller.view addSubview:subViewcontroller.view];
[yourTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:index animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is not just the selected row, I'm changing the table position with a pan gesture and this reloading cause to go back to the original position